# Local Folder in Windows Phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1

i'm using the Local Folder to save a list of objects. To do that i'm also using a json serializer because i want to store those informations in a json file. 
Here is my code:

```
private async void SaveScore(int intscore)
    {
        List<ScoreRecord> recents = await ReadRecentScores();
        if (recents != null)
        {
            if (recents.Count > 10)
            {
                recents.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            recents.Add(new ScoreRecord("defaultName", intscore));
        }
        await WriteRecentScores(recents);
    }

    private async Task WriteRecentScores(List<ScoreRecord> list)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ScoreRecord>));
        using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(
                      RECENTSCOREFILE,
                      CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, list);
        }
    }

    private async Task<List<ScoreRecord>> ReadRecentScores()
    {
        List<ScoreRecord> result = null;
        try
        {
            var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ScoreRecord>));

            var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(RECENTSCOREFILE);

            result = (List<ScoreRecord>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(myStream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

where RECENTSCOREFILE is the name of the file.
I'm not sure if it works, but what i know is that i get a file not found exception when i try to retrieve this file from another page of my app. This is what i'm trying to do:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        recentListBox.ItemsSource = await ReadRecentScores();
    }

    private async Task<List<ScoreRecord>> ReadRecentScores()
    {
        List<ScoreRecord> result;
        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ScoreRecord>));

        var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(RECENTSCOREFILE);

        result = (List<ScoreRecord>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(myStream);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Where and how is RECENTSCOREFILE declared?

Comment: It is declared in both pages this way: const string RECENTSCOREFILE = "score.json";

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Seems like the debugger reaches the piece of code that regards unhandled exceptions (specifically in the App.g.i.cs file)

Comment: You should tell us what the exact error message is. Add the exact error message you get to the question, please.

Comment: I found that it is a file not found exception. I still don't know why that file is not created

Comment: To me it seems like the file is never created

Comment: I'm using my psychic powers here, but if I had to venture a guess: `SaveScore` doesn't return a Task even though it's async, so you're obviously not awaiting it. Could it be that you trigger the navigation to the other page before `SaveScore` had a chance to run fully? You should change the return type to Task and make sure to await it